# Im getting an issue calling APNS notifications from a Node.js server. This is the error I'm getting back

Tags: node.js, apple-push-notifications

{ Error [ERR_HTTP2_STREAM_CANCEL]: The pending stream has been canceled (caused by: unable to get local issuer certificate)

Comment: Im also using pm2 for process running.

Comment: I just solved it. Literally had to upgrade Node to latest stable patch... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Update your Node app to the latest stable version.